# Can't import libraries in jupyter notebook when in a poetry shell

Tags: python-3.x, import, jupyter-notebook, python-poetry

I am learning Python by doing a personal project. I have a poetry shell for my data folder structure. In that folder, I have a jupyter notebook which I use to test my codes. However, after I initiated the `poetry shell` and then ran `poetry add bs4` successfully in the terminal, but then when I ran "import bs4" in a jupyter notebook, it said "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'". And not only just "bs4", but also other libraries like "pandas" or "matplotlib" failed to be imported too.

But when I ran "import bs4" in a normal .py file, it ran successfully. I think the problem might be something about the jupyter notebook and poetry shell. But I tried `poetry add ipkernel` or so but it still said the same Error. Do you know why?

Comment: Jupyter doesn't seem to be seeing the same environment where you are installing in that terminal. You say though it works in a normal `.py` file. But that seems to be using a different environment source than Jupyter.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72390724/8508004) and [corresponding answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77348166/8508004) seem pertinent to your issue here. I think you need to investigate where and what is getting installed in `site-packages` and `~/.local/lib/python...` vs the venv, as "poetry venv doesn't define packages if ...

Comment: <continued> they are already in your system lib/python3.{version} install."